# microSD Card unwriteable after NOOBS installation on RaspberryPi B+

Tags: linux, windows, format, raspberry-pi, sd-card

How I wrote in the title, my 4gb microSD card of unknown brand has became "write protected" after trying to install Raspbian by NOOBS on RaspberryPi B+.
The installation ended with an error and didn't complete, so I tried to format my microSD by PC however it looks simply impossible.
I tried almost anything before write here, following the instruction on this site and similar ones:

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/24736-63-format-write-protected-micro-card

However, on Windows 7 the answer is always the same: "The disk is write protected".
I also tried to format with gparted by ubuntu live cd and at low level, following these instructions:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1510870.

Even though no error messages appear at the end of the tasks, nothing changes inside my microSD.

Do you have any advices or the garbage is the only solution?

Comment: "unknown brand" is not very helpful. Does it have write protection switch? switch it back to off.

Comment: Try this `http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/fix-windows-usb-dvd-download-tool-when-unable-to-copy-files.193386/` on windows

Comment: @Patrick: The microSD card came with a cheap mp3 branded Xtreme, thus the brand name is the same on top of the microSD. I also tried to find the producer's name by Device Manager but nothing. There isn't a protection switch on card and I tried with different adaptors, with and without switch

Comment: @Santosh-A I already tried, It say always that the disk is write protected.